# How can I enable CSS selector profiling in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have read an interesting [article](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/) about css selector profiling but I haven't found any way how to actually enable this feature. Is there something I am completely missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This Answer is no longer valid. Please refer to Johns answer.

Im on Chrome 18.something Dev and its there under Developer Tools.
Click the wrench / Tools / Developer Tools and then click the Profile tab....now to learn what it all means ;)

Comment: that was it - I had the normal version 16.something, thanks ;)

Comment: I just updated to latest chrome (30.something) and seem to have lost the CSS profiler :(

Comment: @AlexandruRada  What happens in a case like this?...any idea?  I guess its up to the original poster to remove my tick and give it to John...Ill edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 13):

The CSS Selector Profiler was [removed from Chrome 30](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265486):

> CSS selector matching is now reasonably fast for the absolute majority of common selectors that used to be slow at the time of the profiler implementation. This time is also included into the Timeline "Recalculate Style" event.
>
> As such, I believe the CSS selector profiler is not as useful as it [might have been] used to and can safely be dropped. This will also reduce the fraction of developers trying to micro-optimize already fast selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still needs the CSS selector profiler, you can find it in the Web Inspector of, I believe, any Webkit-based browser except Safari ([Falkon](https://www.falkon.org/) (formerly known as *Qupzilla*) is just one example).